# Sending message to specific user on Spring Websocket

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-websocket

**How to send websocket message from server to specific user only?**

My webapp has spring security setup and uses websocket. I'm encountering tricky problem trying to send message from server to **specific user only**.

My understanding from reading [the manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#websocket-stomp-handle-user) is from the server we can do

```
simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/user/{username}/reply", reply);
```

And on the client side:

```
stompClient.subscribe('/user/reply', handler);
```

But I could never get the subscription callback invoked. I have tried many different path but no luck.

If I send it to **/topic/reply** it works but all other connected users will receive it too.

To illustrate the problem I've created this small project on github: https://github.com/gerrytan/wsproblem

**Steps to reproduce:**

1) Clone and build the project (make sure you're using jdk 1.7 and maven 3.1)

```
$ git clone https://github.com/gerrytan/wsproblem.git
$ cd wsproblem
$ mvn jetty:run
```

2) Navigate to `http://localhost:8080`, login using either bob/test or jim/test

3) Click "Request user specific msg". Expected: a message "hello {username}" is displayed next to "Received Message To Me Only" for this user only, Actual: nothing is received

Comment: Have you been looking at convertAndSendToUser(String user, String destination, T message) ? http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.M3/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/SimpMessagingTemplate.html#convertAndSendToUser%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20T%29

Comment: Yes tried that too but no luck

Comment: I've been working on private project and this is the method that we use and it is working for us. I think that one potential problem could be that you subscribe to "/user/reply" and you are sending messages to  "/user/{username}/reply". I think that you should remove the {username} part and use the convertAndSendToUser(String user, String destination, T message).

Comment: Thanks but I tried `simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(principal.getName(), "/user/reply", reply);` and when the message is sent from server it throws this exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected destination pattern "/principal/{userId}/**"`

Comment: @ViktorK. is right, and you were quite close to the right solution. Your subscription on client side was correct, you simply had to try: `convertAndSendToUser(principal.getName(), "/reply", reply);`

Answer (score 108):

Oh, `client side no need to known about current user`, server will do that for you.

On server side, using following way to send message to a user:

```
simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(username, "/queue/reply", message);
```

**Note: Using `queue`, not `topic`, Spring always using `queue` with `sendToUser`**

On client side

```
stompClient.subscribe("/user/queue/reply", handler);
```

**Explain**

When any websocket connection is open, Spring will assign it a `session id` (not `HttpSession`, assign per connection). And when your client subscribe to an channel start with `/user/`, eg: `/user/queue/reply`, your server instance will subscribe to a queue named `queue/reply-user[session id]`

When use send message to user, eg: username is `admin`
You will write `simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser("admin", "/queue/reply", message);`

Spring will determine which `session id` mapped to user `admin`. Eg: It found two session `wsxedc123` and `thnujm456`, Spring will translate it to 2 destination `queue/reply-userwsxedc123` and `queue/reply-userthnujm456`, and it send your message with 2 destinations to your message broker.

The message broker receive the messages and provide it back to your server instance that holding session corresponding to each session (WebSocket sessions can be hold by one or more server). Spring will translate the message to `destination` (eg: `user/queue/reply`) and `session id` (eg: `wsxedc123`). Then, it send the message to corresponding `Websocket session`

Comment: Can you please explain how you know the username? in your example you said username is 'admin', you receive the username from user?

Comment: Username was obtained from `HttpSession` when initiate a websocket connection

Comment: please could you give more information about how to set the username?. is there anyway i can send the username on suscription message?

Comment: @Andres: You can extends `DefaultHandshakeHandler` and override method `determineUser`

Comment: @Andres: Send username on subscription is possible but very insecure. Please don't!

Comment: Elaborated on using `determineUser` & `DefaultHandshakeHandler` here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37853727/where-user-comes-from-in-convertandsendtouser-works-in-sockjsspring-websocket

Comment: Your explanation works great. However where is the `queue/reply-user[session id]` part in official document?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan I am following your answer , would you like to look at my question ? thanks . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748468/send-notification-to-specific-user-in-spring-boot-websocket

Comment: I agree with @hbrls, according to the code `super.convertAndSend(this.destinationPrefix + user + destination, payload, headers, postProcessor);`, they do destinationPrefix, then user, THEN destination. Not sure where the "-user" and stuff is being added? Perhaps different version?

Comment: Hello how do we close the connection. I am getting a warning The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [MessageBroker-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [clientInboundChannel-15] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:

Comment: Be aware that you need to change the `WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` as well! With `config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");` in the `configureMessageBroker` method it works.

Answer (score 38):

Ah I found what my problem was. First I didn't register the `/user` prefix on the simple broker

```
<websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic,/user" />
```

Then I don't need the extra `/user` prefix when sending:

```
convertAndSendToUser(principal.getName(), "/reply", reply);
```

Spring will automatically prepend `"/user/" + principal.getName()` to the destination, hence it resolves into "/user/bob/reply".

This also means in javascript I had to subscribe to different address per user

```
stompClient.subscribe('/user/' + userName + '/reply,...)
```

Comment: Mmm... Is there a way to avoid to setup the userName client-side? By changing that value (for example by using another username), you will be able to see messages of others.

Comment: See my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646671/check-auth-while-sending-a-message-to-a-specific-user-by-using-stomp-and-websock/25647822#25647822

Comment: how **subscribe** for to reply to user from methods annotated with `@RequestMapping` and also `@MessageMapping` see here [How to subscribe using Sping Websocket integration on specific userName(userId) + get notifications from method anotated with @RequestMapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47628608/3425489)

Comment: Hey my friend can you tell me this? What is this "user" anyway? I am using Spring Security and my users (username) are email addresses.
When each user logs in he gets his JWT token on Spring Security.

Comment: I faced same problems, searchedfor hours before coming to your answer. ONLY your explination helped me. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3):

My solution of that based on Thanh Nguyen Van's best explanation, but in addition I have configured MessageBrokerRegistry:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/queue/", "/topic/");
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I created a sample websocket project using STOMP as well.
What I am noticing is that

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");// including /user also works
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/getfeeds").withSockJS();
}
```

it works whether or not "/user" is included in config.enableSimpleBroker(...

Answer (score 3):

Exactly i did the same and it is working without using user

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker  
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
       registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic" , "/queue");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, where do you ever use this `/app`? In which case?

Comment: @FranciscoSouza `/app` is usually used for sending messages from the client to the server.

Answer (score 1):

In the following solution, I wrote code snippets for both the client and backend sides. We need to put `/user` at the start of the socket's topic for client code. Otherwise, the client can not listen to the socket.
**Dependency**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**WebSocketConfig.java**

```java
package com.oktaykcr.notificationservice.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/socket").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*");
        registry.addEndpoint("/socket").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/file");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
}
```

**WebSocketContoller.java**

```java
package com.oktaykcr.notificationservice.controller;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class WebSocketController {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketController.class);

    @MessageMapping("/socket")
    @SendTo("/file/status")
    public String fileStatus(@Payload String message) {
        logger.info(message);
        return message;
    }
}
```

You can send message to socket from anywhere. In my case my principal.getName() is equal to userId.

```java
simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(userId, "/file/status", socketMessage);
```

**Client (ReactJs with [react-stomp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-stomp))**
**App.js**

```js
import './App.css';
import SockJsClient from 'react-stomp'
import { useRef } from 'react';

function App() {

  const clientRef = useRef();

  const sendMessage = (msg) => {
    clientRef.current.sendMessage('/app/socket', msg);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => sendMessage("Hola")}>Send</button>
      </div>
      <SockJsClient url='http://localhost:9090/notification-service/socket' topics={['/user/file/status']}
        onMessage={(msg) => { console.log(msg); }}
        ref={(client) => { clientRef.current = client }} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The **url** attribute of the SockJsClient element is `http://localhost:9090/notification-service/socket`. `http://localhost:9090` is  Api Gateway ip address, `notification-service` is name of the microservice and `/socket` is defined in the **WebSocketConfig.java**.