# Check auth while sending a message to a specific user by using STOMP and WebSocket in Spring

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp, spring-messaging

I'm developing a realtime notification system in **Spring 4** by using a build-in **Message Broker**, and **STOMP** over **WebSocket**.

I would like to be able to send messages to a specific user, according with his username.
In order to achieve this goal, I'm using the `convertAndSendToUser` method of `org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate` class, as follows:

```
private final MessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

@Autowired
public LRTStatusListener(SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate) {
    this.messagingTemplate = messagingTemplate;
}


@Scheduled(fixedDelay=5000)
public void sendMessages(Principal principal)
    messagingTemplate
        .convertAndSendToUser(principal.getName(), "/horray", "Horray, " + principal.getName() + "!");
}
```

As configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/notifications").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue", "/user");
    }

}
```

Client-side (via **JavaScript**), I should subscribe to a channel by specifing the username (according with another very similar question: **[Sending message to specific user on Spring Websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367223/sending-message-to-specific-user-on-spring-websocket)**).

```
stompClient.subscribe('/user/' + username + '/horray, ...)
```

This last point sounds weird...

Supposing that I'm logged as *w.white* on my webapp, by subscribing:

```
stompClient.subscribe('/user/w.white/horray, ...)
```

... I will be able to see messages sent to *w.white*, and this is awesome... But subscribing:

```
stompClient.subscribe('/user/j.pinkman/horray, ...)
```

... I will be able to see also messages sent to *j.pinkman*, despide that I'm currently logged as *w.white*.

It is a way to overcome this problem?

---

### Update

Below there is the log about the connection over WebSocket:

```
Opening Web Socket... 
Web Socket Opened... 
>>> CONNECT
accept-version:1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000

<<< CONNECTED
user-name:w.white
heart-beat:0,0
version:1.1

connected to server undefined
Connected: CONNECTED
version:1.1
heart-beat:0,0
user-name:w.white

>>> SUBSCRIBE
id:sub-0
destination:/topic/lrt

>>> SUBSCRIBE
id:sub-1
destination:/user/lrt
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found the solution.

First of all, it is important to know that the `/user` channel is already managed by **Spring STOMP**, and by the way, no registration is required.

So:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
}
```

Then, I setup the destination channel as `/queue/horray`:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay=5000)
public void sendMessages(Principal principal)
    messagingTemplate
        .convertAndSendToUser(principal.getName(), "/queue/horray", "Horray, " + principal.getName() + "!");
}
```

At last, on client:

```
stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/horray', '...');
```

Now, it works fine! Messages are sent only to the specified recipient, according to the `Principal` fetched by the security context.

Comment: Congratulations on your solution. Do you know if there would be a similar version using the @SendToUser annotation?

Comment: It should be the same. Have you tried using `@SendToUser` with `/user/queue/horray` as destination?

Comment: Yes. For some weird reason it did not worked (client never received the subscription callback, even if the method had being called successfully). My solution was to add a custom header ("toUser") and send the message using SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser. I retrieve the headers adding the Message<?> message parameter in the controller method. User is subscribed to '/user/topic/chat'. If you subscribe to '/user/{username}/topic/chat' you do not receive the messages (which is intended). Also, there is no need to enable "/user" as a broker.

Comment: My conf almost same with yours (I'm using queue/reply instead of queue/horray) but my console output is empty. Did you skip some important points in your post or that's all? Could you post total config?

Comment: Hello, @vdenotaris. I have noticed your scheduled method for publishing messages:

@Scheduled(fixedDelay=5000)
public void sendMessages(Principal principal)
    messagingTemplate
        .convertAndSendToUser(principal.getName(), "/queue/horray", "Horray, " + principal.getName() + "!");
}


Spring scheduled methods do not work with parameters. How can I get Principal inside the scheduled method? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any method annotated with @Scheduled can not accept any argument. @Scheduled(fixedDelay=5000) public void sendMessages(Principal principal){} this will not work.

Comment: This question had been published and accepted 3 years ago. Please, stop with the necroposting!

Comment: @vdenotaris I'm not using Spring security `:-(`, How do I get user here `messagingTemplate
        .convertAndSendToUser(?, "/queue/horray", "Horray, ?");`

Answer (score 7):

Since users on my application are not authenticated I just used the session Id to differenciate the various topics

on the server:

```
template.convertAndSend("/topic/warnings/" + sessionId, ...)
```

And the client is pretty straightforward

```
stompClient.subscribe('/topic/warnings/${pageContext.session.id}', ...
```

Maybe not the cleanest way but it works, and without authentication I couldn't make use of /user channel

Comment: I my case If **two users** are logged into the **same `browser`**, their `sessionId` will be the same, so one can see other's subscriptions, this should be done on user_id or user_name...

Comment: @ShantaramTupe ***two users** are logged into the **same browser*** is not a valid case IMHO. In that case you will have to switch the sessions internally. Then again, practically and ultimately it won't be multiple users, but a single user having multiple accounts. (Gmail for an instance, you could think of)..