# Send Notification to specific user in spring boot websocket

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, stomp, spring-websocket

I want to send notification to specific client.

e.g username user

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends
    AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

        @Override
        public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
            stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/socket")
                    .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                    .withSockJS();
        }

        @Override
        public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
            registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
            registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");

        }
```

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping("/notify")
public String getNotification(Principal principal) {
    String username = "user";

    notifications.increment();
    logger.info("counter" + notifications.getCount() + "" + principal.getName());
    //  logger.info("usersend:"+sha.getUser().getName()) ; //user

    template.convertAndSendToUser(principal.getName(), "queue/notification", notifications);

    return "Notifications successfully sent to Angular !";
}
```

**Client-Side**

Angular Service

```
connect() {
    let socket = new SockJs(`api/socket`);

    let stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

    return stompClient;
}
```

Angular Component

```
 let stompClient = this.webSocketService.connect();

     stompClient.connect({}, frame => {

      stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/notification', notifications => {
               console.log('test'+notifications)
          this.notifications = JSON.parse(notifications.body).count;

      })     });
```

I am have searched many other questions and tried but none of them worked for me 
e.g [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367223/sending-message-to-specific-user-on-spring-websocket) answered by Thanh Nguyen Van and  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646671/check-auth-while-sending-a-message-to-a-specific-user-by-using-stomp-and-websock/25647822#25647822)

**Console**

```
 Opening Web Socket...
    stomp.js:134 Web Socket Opened...
    stomp.js:134 >>> CONNECT
    accept-version:1.1,1.0
    heart-beat:10000,10000


    stomp.js:134 <<< CONNECTED
    version:1.1
    heart-beat:0,0


    stomp.js:134 connected to server undefined
    reminder.component.ts:18 test callsed
    stomp.js:134 >>> SUBSCRIBE
    id:sub-0
    destination:/user/queue/notification
```

thanks in advance .

Comment: I have implemented stomp and it is working, the problem is that when I close my server then I get a warning -- The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [MessageBroker-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer of [gerrytan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179630/gerrytan) to [Sending message to specific user on Spring Websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367223/sending-message-to-specific-user-on-spring-websocket) mentions a web socket configuration change, to register the `/user` prefix. In your case I guess it means to replace

```
registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
```

with

```
registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue", "/user");
```

He also says that in controller you don't need the `/user` prefix because it is added automatically. So you could try this:

```
template.convertAndSendToUser(principal.getName(), "/queue/notification", notifications);
```

and this:

```
template.convertAndSendToUser(principal.getName(), "/user/queue/notification", notifications);
```

On the client side you need to provide the username that you used to connect to server.  You might insert it directly:

```
stompClient.subscribe('/user/naila/queue/notification', ...)
```

or get it from a header.  But [Markus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/606662/markus-pscheidt) says at [How to send websocket message to concrete user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50044077/how-to-send-websocket-message-to-concrete-user) that even here you don't need the username, so it might work like this:

```
stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/notification', ...)
```

Comment: how do we handle closing the websocket connection for a particular user?

Comment: What is there to handle? How a connection would be closed for a particular user? Anyway, this is unrelated to the original post, you should post this as a distinct question.

Comment: Hi edixon your answer is very helpful. I have implemented stomp and it is working, the problem is that when I close my server then I get a warning -- The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [MessageBroker-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Comment: Your question has several answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48254517/. I found it at the top when googling for "the web application appears to have started".

Comment: Hello thanks for url but it discusses other issue. Were you not getting any thread or memory leak warning after terminating your app locally when you implemented your solution.

Answer (score 7):

Seems you are missing a slash in your destination:

```
template.convertAndSendToUser(principal.getName(), "/queue/notification", notifications);
```

Comment: Check the Spring Websocket Chat sample, might help you https://github.com/salmar/spring-websocket-chat

Comment: can i find what path has been produced by this line in spring   template.convertAndSendToUser(.....) ?