# Why Spring SendToUser does not work

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp, sockjs

I just followed up the instruction from spring to send back response to particular user, not broadcast message instead.but in the end, No response message can be sent back.

this is my js code:

```
var stompClient = null;
function setConnected(connected) {
    document.getElementById('connect').disabled = connected;
    document.getElementById('disconnect').disabled = !connected;
    document.getElementById('conversationDiv').style.visibility = 
            connected ? 'visible': 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = '';
}
function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('reqsample');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('user/queue/resp', function(resp) {
            var body = JSON.parse(resp.body);
            showResp('cmid:' + body.cmid + ',reqName:' + body.reqName
                    + ',custNo:' + body.custNo + ',qty:' + body.quantity);
        });
        stompClient.subscribe('user/queue/errors', function(resp) {
            var body = JSON.parse(resp.body);
            showResp(body);
        });
    });
}
function disconnect() {
    stompClient.disconnect();
    setConnected(false);
    console.log("Disconnected");
}
function sendName() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    stompClient.send("/app/req", {}, JSON.stringify({
        'name' : name
    }));
}
```

This is controller:

```
@Controller
public class MessageController {
    @MessageMapping("/req")
    @SendToUser("/queue/resp")
    public RespMessage greeting(ReqMessage message, Principal pc)
        throws Exception {
    System.out.println("---- received message: " + message == null ? "NULL"
            : message.getName());
    System.out.println("---- received user info: " + pc.getName());
    RespMessage rm = new RespMessage();
    rm.setCmid("CM_01");
    rm.setCustNo("Cust_02");
    rm.setQuantity("1000");
    rm.setReqName(message.getName());
    return rm;

    }

    @MessageExceptionHandler
    @SendToUser("/queues/errors")
    public String handleException(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        return ex.getMessage();
    }

    }
```

This is spring configuration:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="wx.poc7" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
<websocket:message-broker
    application-destination-prefix="/app" user-destination-prefix="/user">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="reqsample">
        <websocket:sockjs />
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/queue, /topic" />
 </websocket:message-broker>
```

pls help. thx in advance.

I have tried use @SendToUser ,@SendToUser("/queue/resp") and SimpMessagingTemplate as well, totally cannot respond message to browser.

Answer (score 8):

User destinations prefix is `/user` but it seems you are missing the `/` in your subscription destination. Change `user/queue/resp` to `/user/queue/resp` to receive the messages on your client side.

Comment: oh, my god! it works just add / to prefix user, then /user works. thx a lot, save me a lot time

Answer (score 0):

Your WebSocket configuration looks good, but I think the issue is with the correct `connect` URL:

```
new SockJS('reqsample')
```

Be sure that this URL is valid. I see that you use the same for `stomp-endpoint path="reqsample"`. But don't forget that there is a `DispatcherServlet` mapping in the `web.xml`.

Try to use the `full` url from the `SockJS` constructor including host and port. Like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/reqsample
```

If your `DispatcherServlet` is mapped to the `/`.

When you figure out the correct URL for your STOMP endpoint you can play with relative path from that JSP.

Answer (score 0):

When in Javascript you subscribe the channel:

```
stompClient.subscribe('user/queue/errors', function(resp) {
            var body = JSON.parse(resp.body);
            showResp(body);
        });
```

the right path is 'user/'+ username +'queue/errors'

look this topic too: 
[Sending message to specific user on Spring Websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367223/sending-message-to-specific-user-on-spring-websocket)