# Real time notifications in spring boot web socket

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

In my application, I need to send real time notifications to a specific user.
My `WebSocketConfig` class is as below,

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
    public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
        @Override
        public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
            stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/websocket-example")
                    .withSockJS();
        }

        @Override
        public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
            registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }
}
```

Most of the time information will be sent by the server side. So I have not set the application destination.

In the client side, I am subscribing to the destination '/topic/user`,

```
function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('/websocket-example');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/user', function (greeting) {
//            showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
console.log("Received message through WS");
        });
    });
}
```

In one of my `RestController` I have a method which broadcasts the message to all connected clients.

```
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public void test()
    {
        template.convertAndSend("/topic/user", "Hurray");
    }
```

Until this part everything works fine. I receive the message and is logging to the console.

Now If I want to send the notification only to specific users, I have to use `template.convertAndSendToUser(String user, String destination, String message)`. But I am not understanding what I should pass to the `user` parameter. Where and when will I get the `user`?

I went through couple of questions related to this, but I am not understanding the concepts clearly.

Comment: Are you using spring security?

Answer (score 2):

Before sending any messages to a user you need to authenticate it by the server first. There are different ways for doing this. Spring Security is a key phrase here

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/helloworld-boot.html

When authentication is completed you can simply get user name by calling:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String currentPrincipalName = authentication.getName();
```

https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security

Answer (score 0):

This `username` is part of a `java.security.Principal interface`. Each StompHeaderAccessor or WebSocket session object has an instance of this principle and you can get the username from it. it is not generated automatically. `It has to be generated manually by the server for every session.`

You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37853727/where-user-comes-from-in-convertandsendtouser-works-in-sockjsspring-websocket) for more info about generating a unique id for every session.

then use like this:

```
@MessageMapping('/test')
public void test(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor sha)
{
  String userName = sha.session.principal.name;
  template.convertAndSend(userName, '/topic/user', "Hurray");
}
```

Comment: I can access `SimpMessageHeaderAccessor` in a method annotated with `@MessageMapping('/test')`. But I am not receiving data from client side. I should be able to send notification to any user from any method.

Comment: you have to maintain a unique id for every session from client request and then use `convertAndSend` method to push notification for a specific client with their session id that you assigned to same.

Comment: And where will I get that Id? Can you please edit your answer accordingly

Comment: take reference from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37853727/where-user-comes-from-in-convertandsendtouser-works-in-sockjsspring-websocket