# Difference between /topic, /queue for SimpleMessageBroker in Spring Websocket + SockJS

Tags: java, spring, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

Is there a clarification,  what is the differences between /topic, /queue etc. for Spring Websocket + SockJS in case I am using "simple broker" ? E.g. here [Sending message to specific user on Spring Websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367223/sending-message-to-specific-user-on-spring-websocket) it is said: ***when your client subscribe to an channel start with /user/, eg: /user/queue/reply, your server instance will subscribe to a queue named queue/reply-user[session id]***

I would like to understand the logic behind such conversions in some clear way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should take a look at [this part of the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#websocket-stomp-message-flow).
In a nutshell, `"/topic"` and `"/queue"` are both prefixes configured to the same destination.

In the documentation, `"/app"` is the configured "application destination prefix" - meaning all messages flowing in through the `"clientInboundChannel"` and matching those prefixes will be mapped to your application, for example with `@MessageMapping` annotations.

Here also, `"/topic"` and `"/queue"` are both prefixes configured as STOMP destinations - meaning all messages flowing in through the `"clientInboundChannel"` and matching those prefixes will be forwarded to the STOMP broker. In your case, that's the simple broker implementation.

So from Spring Websocket's point of view, `"/queue"` and `"/topic"` are treated the same way and are "typical" STOMP destinations - all messages matching those are forwarded to the messages broker. Now if you're using a full message broker implementation, those destinations may not have the same meaning and the message broker behavior could be different. Here are some examples with [Apache Apollo](https://activemq.apache.org/apollo/documentation/stomp-manual.html#Destination_Types) and [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html#d).

Note that if you want to, you can change those prefixes. But I would advise you to keep those as defaults unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: Can you please comment, what would be actually the difference between /topic and /queue? It is now not clear, should I use either of them or can just make up my own.

Comment: I've updated my answer. For the simple message broker, it makes no difference at all. But I've made clear that with real message brokers (if you need to deploy multiple instances of your application), those destinations may have different meanings.

Comment: The linked part of the reference documentation only mentions the handling of messages that come from the client. What about messages that go to the clients? Are they broadcasted on /topic/ and first come first served on /queue/, or always broadcasted?

Answer (score 9):

I think the best answer for that topic would be the following from Spring Docs

> The meaning of a destination is intentionally left opaque in the STOMP
>   spec. **It can be any string**, and it’s entirely up to STOMP servers to
>   define the semantics and the syntax of the destinations that they
>   support. **It is very common, however, for destinations to be path-like
>   strings where "/topic/.." implies publish-subscribe (one-to-many) and
>   "/queue/" implies point-to-point (one-to-one) message exchanges.**

Answer (score 6):

There is a bigger and more important difference not mentioned in the answers above.

Topic is auto-delete whereas queue is durable. It means that when the websocket connection is closed, the topic and its data is removed. in queue, the server can still send messages and when client connect via websocket, it receives old sent messages by server.

By the way, there is no difference in in-memory broker. This happens when using dedicated broker.

Comment: Can you please add a reference to the relevant documentation?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.M4/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-enable documentation says "The "/topic" and "/queue" prefixes depend on the broker in use" and "Check the STOMP page of the broker to see the destination semantics it supports". The answer I mentioned was for RabbitMQ. I don't know if other brokers are like that.