# ConvertAndSendToUser SpringStomp Sockjs not working SimpMessagingTemplate

Tags: spring, websocket, queue, stomp, sockjs

I want to send notification to specific user. My client side code is:

```
stompClient.connect({},function (frame) {
   stompClient.subscribe('user/queue/notification', function(response){
     alert(angular.fromJson(response.body));
   });
```

Here's my server configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/queue");
}


@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/myWebSocketEndPoint")
            .setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .withSockJS();
    }
}
```

Here's my server message-sender:

```
@Component
public class MenuItemNotificationSender {
    public void sendNotification(MenuItemDto menuItem, String username) {
        String address = "/queue/notification";
        System.out.println(username);
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(username,address, menuItem);
    }
}
```

The messages are sent correctly, to the correct username, but why client doesn't receive them?

Comment: you js client subscribed to `user/queue/notification` but you send message to `String username`. does it have something in common?

Comment: I'm not sending to String "username", i use convert and send to user which automatically should add to my address the session id of the user identified by username. The string username contains the username of a user

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367223/sending-message-to-specific-user-on-spring-websocket

Comment: you've subscribed to 'user/queue/notification' that is hardcode string. it will process only 'user/queue/notification', not a 'user123/queue/notification' or 'user456/queue/notification'

Comment: Maybe you have configured st wrong. Does client receive broadcast messages: 
      "messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(address, menuItem);
?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11496

Comment: here are some working examples which might help:
https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio.git

Comment: subscribe path needed to start with a slash `/user/queue/notification` ?