# How can I send message to the specific clients via websockets in Spring Webflux?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-websocket, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I developed web chat with ReactJS\redux in Client and spring-boot-starter-webflux\Reactor\Spring Boot 2 in Server.

Server developed like [here](http://blog.monkey.codes/how-to-build-a-chat-app-using-webflux-websockets-react/).

Clint receives the messages that way:

```
this.clientWebSocket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/websocket/chat");
this.clientWebSocket.onopen = function() {
    }
    this.clientWebSocket.onclose = function() {
    }
    this.clientWebSocket.onerror = function() {
    }
    var _this = this;
    this.clientWebSocket.onmessage = function(dataFromServer) {
        _this.updateMessages(dataFromServer);
    }
```

One message will be send to all clients. **How can I send message to the specific clients via websockets?** Not for all.

I found some giudes with SockJS, but I want to use Spring Webflux\Reactor.

**UPDATE:**

I have the following configuration in server:

```
@Bean
public HandlerMapping webSocketMapping(UnicastProcessor<Event> eventPublisher, Flux<Event> events) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("/websocket/chat", new ChatSocketHandler(eventPublisher, events));
    SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
    simpleUrlHandlerMapping.setUrlMap(map);

    simpleUrlHandlerMapping.setOrder(10);
    return simpleUrlHandlerMapping;
}
```

So I send message to the **/websocket/chat** path from the client.

Can I set up this path to Client1 send message to **/websocket/chat/chat1** and Client2 send message to **/websocket/chat/chat2**? So **/websocket/chat/chat1** and **/websocket/chat/chat2** are different chats.

For example, Client1 and Client3 recive the messages of **/websocket/chat/chat1**, but they does not recive messages of **/websocket/chat/chat2**?

Number of the chats can change dynamically depending on the clients activity.

Answer (score 1):

Websocket is a Client-Server protocol, so a sending from a client to another client is only doable via the server as the mediator. What you need to accomplish is to implement a fuctionality at the server, that if a specific message (e.g. special custom header information) is received, you need to dispatch that to the corresponding client (e.g. client-ID).

Sending a Websocket from a client directly to another client is not possible because of the protocol.

There are several [convertAndSendToUser(..)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/SimpMessageSendingOperations.html#convertAndSendToUser-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) methods available in the Spring WebSocketTemplate. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31577152/1905015). It describes the way in very detail.

Comment: thank you for the response. Please see my updated question. I want to undestand HOW can I "dispatch that to the corresponding client (e.g. client-ID)"

Comment: Note that the method you linked is for the Stomp protocol, which reactive websockets doesn't seem to use.