# Set principal.getName() in destination topic with Spring Websocket

Tags: spring-websocket

I'm using spring WebSocket and I don't know how to send messages to a specific partition that contains the username.

i.e.:

```
@MessageMapping("/getNotifications")
@SendTo("/topic/notifications")
public @ResponseBody List<NotificationResponse> getNotificationsWS(int size,
        SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor, Principal principal) throws Exception {
    ActionResult<List<NotificationResponse>> notificationsAr;
    notificationsAr = this.listNotifications(size, principal);
    return notificationsAr.getResult();

}
```

I'm trying to send the messages to "/topic/notifications/myUserName" instead of "/topic/notifications". In this way each logged user consumes from his own partition.

How I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to inject `SimpMessagingTemplate` and then you can `simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(username, "/queue/reply", message);`

Take a look at Thanh [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367223/sending-message-to-specific-user-on-spring-websocket#answer-31577152)